# Python MSS for Python3.4

Tags: python, python-mss

Iam developing a software to record screen, and currently using the screenshot module from mss package.
But i need that software to work with python 3.4 and cant find a suitable version from mss lib, does someone know how to install that package on python3.4 ? Or recommends a better substitute ?

Comment: The documentation says it'll work on 3.5, 3.6, 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Official page](https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/releases) versions 3.1.2 are compatible with Python 3.4.

Enter the following command:
`pip install mss==3.1.2`